# How to solve packages dependency when install pycaret package?

Tags: python, pycaret

I created a environment, and install pycaret package like this.

```py
conda create -n env_pycaret python=3.10.* pip ipykernel 
conda activate env_pycaret
```

and install from `conda` with command following. It's run for longtime, I don't see it stop.

```
conda install -c conda-forge pycaret
```

Cause I can't install `pycaret` by conda, I used `pip`, a lot of packages are conflicted.

```
pip install pycaret
```

I don't know how to install correctly. Please help me.
Thank you!

## Update

Now I installed `pycaret` version 3.0 with simple steps

```
# create new environment
conda create -n env_pycaret python=3.10.* pip ipykernel 
conda activate env_pycaret
# install library pycaret or pycaret[full] up to you
pip install pycaret
```

Comment: I recommend using `conda` or `pip`, but don't mix them.

Comment: Also, what do you mean "a lot of packages are conflicted"? Do you get an error? If so, please [edit] your question to include the entire error.

Comment: I used conda to create new environment only. Because lastest pycaret 3.0 is not avaiable in conda repositories, that I have to use `pip`. From version pycaret 3.0, I did following these steps and don't have any conflict

Comment: Is your "update" section a solution that works for you? If so, you should put it in the answer section below instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now I installed `pycaret` version 3.0 with no conflict.

```
# create new environment
conda create -n env_pycaret python=3.10.* pip ipykernel 
conda activate env_pycaret
# install library pycaret or pycaret[full] up to you
pip install pycaret
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pip install pycaret[full]
```

Comment: From version pycaret 3.0, i can install it with no conflict